# Which is the lowest or most accurate upper bound formula for the maximum gap in sieve of Eratosthenes after a particular iteration?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, sieve-theory

Consider a function $a(x)$ which gives the larget gap in the sieve of Eratosthenes after  the $x^{th}$ iteration.

So,

$a(0) = 0$

$a(1) = 1$, After removing the multiples of 2.

$a(2) = 3$, After removing the multiples of 3.

$a(3) = 5$, After removing the multiples of 5.

$a(4) = 9$, After removing the multiples of 7.

Is there a formula to calculate $G(x)$ for any given number? If a specific formula is not available, is there an upper bound formula which gives the upper bound for $G(x)$

---

P.S: After the $x^{th}$ iteration of the sieve, there seems to emerge a repeating pattern with the cycle width of product of all the prime numbers used till the $x^{th}$ iteration. After the $1^{st}$ iteration there is a pattern cycle of width two. After the $2^{nd}$ iteration a width of six(2×3). After the $3^{rd}$  iteration the width of the cycle is 30(2×3×5).

---

Bounty Edit: [The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574061/1115576) by [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin) says there is no closed formula and it points to [OEIS A058989](https://oeis.org/A058989) series page, which says

> Iwaniec proved that a(n) << n^2*(log n)^2. - Charles R Greathouse IV,
> Sep 08 2012

So there seems to be an upper bound to this function. The upper bound says the maximum gap is lesser than $n^2*(log n)^2$, here $n$ is the nth prime number.

Can we use this to somehow to prove that
$$a(n) << q^2 - q$$
where $q$ is $n^{th}$ prime number.

Or

$$a(n) << p^2 - q$$
where $p$ is $(n+1)^{th}$ and $q$ is $n^{th}$ prime number.

Comment: I haven't read it carefully, but [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88323/analogues-of-jacobsthals-function) appears to have some discussion of upper bounds for your function.

Answer (score 2):

This is one less than the [Jacobsthal function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function) evaluated at the product of the first $n$ primes. The exact sequence on OEIS (which we should always search to see if our sequence is already known) is [sequence A058989](https://oeis.org/A058989); see [sequence A048670](https://oeis.org/A048670) for more information. No closed formula is known, (And yes, after the $x$th sieve iteration, the pattern is periodic with length equal to the product of the first $x$ primes.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the actual function OP is asking about is sequence [A058989](https://oeis.org/A058989) on OEIS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you can edit it to make it better with the question edit. Thanks