# Which is the lowest or most accurate upper bound formula for the maximum gap in this modified sieve of Eratosthenes after a particular iteration?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, sieve-theory

As I discuss a similar question regarding the best upper bound for maximum gap after $n^{th}$ iteration of sieve of Eratosthenes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574022/which-is-the-lowest-or-most-accurate-upper-bound-formula-for-the-maximum-gap-in), I'm interested to know whether such a thing is possible for a modified sieve of Eratosthenes where every multiple of a prime number and numbers which have remainder two for that prime number will be sieved.

So any number $k$ will be sieved if $k\bmod q = 0$ or $2$, where $q$ is the prime number.

**In such a modified sieve, what is the best upper bound formula for the maximum gap after the $n^{th}$ iteration?**

---

Is it possible to prove that

$$a(n) \ll q^2 - q$$

Or

$$a(n) \ll p^2 - q$$

where
$a(n)$ is the upper bound,
$p$ is $(n+1)^{th}$ prime number and
$q$ is $n^{th}$ prime number.

Comment: What is the limit upto which we sieve the numbers ?

Comment: @Peter the pattern if sieves start repeating with period of product of prime numbers used to sieve. For example after sieving for 2, 3 and 5, the pattern repeats every 30 numbers once. After 7, it starts repeating after 210 numbers once. So the limit is probably the product of all the prime numbers used till now for sieving. This was pointed out in the answerto the question which is linked in this question.

Comment: @Peter see this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574061/1115576

Answer (score 1):

After $n$ sieving steps, there is one residue class mod 2 remaining and $p-2$ residue classes mod each of $p_2=3,p_3=5,\ldots,p_n$. Hence there are $k_nx+O_n(1)$ unsieved numbers up to $x$, where
$$
k_n = \frac12\prod_{3 \le q \le p_n}\frac{p-2}{p}
$$

If you sieve up to $\sqrt x$ rather than to some fixed $n$, then you get $\ll x/\log^2 x$ by the Brun sieve.